# nginx server block not being picked up

Tags: nginx, debian

I have nginx running on Raspbian and I'm trying to add another server block alongside the default one. I have two files `default` and `blog.mydomain.com` where mydomain is obviously my own domain. In the `default` file I have:

http://pastebin.com/bVWSLMf5

This works fine, and when I visit via mydomain.com via 8080 I get the standard '

> Welcome to nginx!

The second file, `blog.mydomain.com` is:

http://pastebin.com/PtCECSE4

When I visit http://blog.mydomian.com:8080 I get the default welcome message again.  I have something in the folder (a wordpress install which I have been hosting elsewhere), so I'm really not sure why I'm not seeing it?

Comment: Where are the 2 files you mentioned? Have you enabled the sites and relaoded nginx?

Comment: They're in /etc/nginx/sites-available with symlinks in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try specifying a server_name in your first server block.  I suspect something is happening in the server name mapping so that both names are resolving to the same root.

See:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name

For more info on server names.

Comment: I've added dev.mydomain.com to the default server block, and wierdly it points directs me to a site on another server I'm hosting..... seriously considering moving back to apache at this point :P

Comment: That sounds like a DNS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so weirdly if I combine the two files together inside `default` it works as expected. For reference I now have this in a single file:

http://pastebin.com/hVJLTHBv

Comment: In you main nginx.conf file, what include statements are there? Perhaps only the default file and not the entire directory was being included.

Comment: I checked and include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; is in there.